# In breadcrumb site listed twice moss 2007

Tags: 2007, navigation, branding

On *some* of our pages the breadcrumb lists a site twice in a row.  the first one is a link, the second is not.  The pages have different payout pages.   Has anyone seen this, or know how to fix it?

Comment: Any chance you could post the code for those breadcrumbs? From the Working/non-working page layouts?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem i.e. site names appearing twice (one with hyperlink and other without hyperlink). Please let me know if a solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when you also deploy a custom built breadcrumb and don't deactivate the out of the box SharePoint breadcrumb. Try adding the following line of code in your custom layout to deactivate the SharePoint:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content6" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server" />
```

This line should be in all your custom layouts that will display your custom bradcrumb and not the one SharePoint provides.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that page should be a customized page, please open the page (custom page/master page) in a SharePoint designer and see if the breadcrumb code exists twice.

Comment: it's not the whole breadcrumb that is listed twice, just one of the sites...     for example ...    root / site1 / subsite1 / subsite1 / library /

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this... http://www.sharepointalism.com/index.php?id=5

If the picture looks like what you are experiencing there is a fix contained in the post.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a global breadcrumb that is used at a site collection level for linking them together and then there is a local breadcrumb for navigating your subsite structures.  On the masterpage you should be able to see both of these.  I am not sure if this is your problem, but it might be something to look at.